# command not found - when every param on new line

Tags: bash, maven

In bash file `myBuildAndJacoco.sh`:

```
mvn -Pcommon,coverage 
clean 
org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent 
install 
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
-Dclient.version=0.2-SNAPSHOT 
-Djacoco.outputDir=${WORKSPACE}/target
```

But when I run it I get error:

```
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 12: clean: command not found
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 14: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent: command not found
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 15: -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true: command not found
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 16: -Dclient.version=0.2-SNAPSHOT: command not found
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 17: -Dngnms.version=-SNAPSHOT: command not found
./myBuildAndJacoco.sh: line 18: -Djacoco.outputDir=/target: No such file or directory
```

I need to split all this params to new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bash script run thinks of everything written on a new line as a part of a new command.

for example when running this code

```
mvn -Pcommon,coverage 
clean
```

it thinks of mvn ... as one command and clean as another. To prevent it you can use a \ and the end of each line. For example

```
mvn -Pcommon,coverage \
clean
```

similarly your entire code should be

```
mvn -Pcommon,coverage \
clean \
org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent \
install \
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \
-Dclient.version=0.2-SNAPSHOT \
-Djacoco.outputDir=${WORKSPACE}/target
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WORKSPACE="wahtever"

OPTS=()
OPTS+=("-Pcommon,coverage") 
OPTS+=("clean") 
OPTS+=("org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent") 
OPTS+=("install") 
OPTS+=("-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true")
OPTS+=("-Dclient.version=0.2-SNAPSHOT") 
OPTS+=("-Djacoco.outputDir=${WORKSPACE}/target")
# mvn "${OPTS[@]}" 
echo mvn "${OPTS[@]}" 


mvn -Pcommon,coverage clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dclient.version=0.2-SNAPSHOT -Djacoco.outputDir=wahtever/target
```